# Android Spinner value retrieved from database and dynamic selected item

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-spinner

Hi All I need your help.
I am currently having problems regarding to Android spinner.
Well, I have two spinners, one for source language and the other for target language. these two spinners values contain language list retrieved from database. For example in database I have list of language:
language_code(en,kr,jp,chinese),  description (English,Korean,Japanese,Chinese).
The first spinner will contain all the language description whereas the second one will contain all except the selected one in the 1st spinner.
if the selected item in the 1st spinner is English then the values in 2nd spinner must be only the rest exclude English.
What I want is the user can change the languages any time they want, so when the spinner value is changed, user have to click a button to trigger the change and then using the intent to pass to the same class but with the different spinner value. And what I want is the spinner selected item for source and target are from the previous selection.

I have done with the spinner but I have idea with the dynamic change. Any idea?

Thank you